# Starting Drill in Ubuntu

Tags: apache-drill

I am starting Apache Drill (ver:-1.8) in Ubuntu OS in Embedded Mode, but its showing error:-

`No known driver to handle "jdbc:drill:zk=local"`
I am following same procedure as given in Drill Official Site- [Drill Doc](https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-linux-and-mac-os-x/)

I have install java 7 in my system but still my drill is not started. Can anyone tell me how to start drill in ubuntu os.?

Comment: How are you starring drill - embedded mode or cluster node ? What is the command used ?

Comment: @devツ:-    sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"

Comment: @devツ:- I have started my drill in embedded mode. Command :- sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-linux-and-mac-os-x/) mentioned by you,

> To start the Drill shell in embedded mode, use the drill-embedded command. Internally, the command uses a jdbc connection string and identifies the local node as the ZooKeeper node. Complete the following steps to start the Drill shell:

1. Navigate to the Drill installation directory (*information provided ibn comment*).

   ```
   cd /media/ejeeva/B014055E14052944/apache-drill-1.8.0
   ```
2. Issue the following command to start the Drill shell:

   ```
   bin/drill-embedded
   ```

Comment: :- I have fire this command also. But While Firing this command.  This error showing:-`bash: bin/drill-embedded: No such file or directory`

Comment: from where are you firing this command(`bin/drill-embedded`)? fire `pwd` and tell me the location

Comment: :-This is my location   `/media/ejeeva/B014055E14052944/apache-drill-1.8.0`

Comment: @Sanjiv fire the two commands shared by me in the updated answer

Comment: :- same thing i am doing. Its Showing This.. `-bash: bin/drill-embedded: Permission denied
`

Comment: change permission for `/media/ejeeva/B014055E14052944/apache-drill-1.8.0` folder from root user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124765/discussion-between-sanjiv-and-dev-).